# Можно ли указать условия выполнения внутри sql скрипта?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

У меня есть инструмент для прогона sql - скриптов на проде.
Один файл - один sql-скрипт.
Есть ли в sql такой синтаксис, что если чего-то не найдено, например таблицы, не выполнять ничего?

В моем случае, на одном сервере есть ограничение  UK8ut91db3xdtls2x61e63iwym4, а на другом - нет

На первом скрипт удаления ограничения отрабатывает нормально, но на втором - падает с ошибкой

```
cannot drop UK8ut91db3xdtls2x61e63iwym4 constraint not exist
```

сам скрипт:

```
alter table UserRecord drop constraint UK8ut91db3xdtls2x61e63iwym4
```

Использую базу Oracle 11g с Oracle диалектом.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161496/drop-foreign-key-only-if-it-exists  Это если у вас вдруг MySQL. А так для каждой СУБД могут быть свои методы. Поэтому _всегда_ в вопросах по SQL указывайте какую БД вы используете

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать конструкцию типа :

```
Begin
%your_script%
Exception
When OTHERS
Then
Rollback;
End;
```